# How to one way bind the selected text value of a ComboBox to a property of an object

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, binding

I have a combobox that's set to `DropDownStyle=DropDownList` (meaning users can't type anything, just select from dropdown).  The combo contains a list of states.

I am trying to bind the selected text value to _model.StateBar, but my code doesn't seem to update the property of the object.

I've tried both of the following:

```
cboStates.DataBindings.Add("Text", _model, "StateBar")
cboStates.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", _model, "StateBar")
cboStates.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", _model, "StateBar")
```

I just need to bind it one way: updates from the control need to end up on the object.

Comment: `SelectedValue`, `Text` and `SelectedItem` work properly. Just keep in mind the to set allowed values to `DataSource` and also property value will change after the combo box lost focus. To change this behavior, you can use other overload of adding binding `..., true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);`.

Comment: is your combobox situated on a tabpage by any chance? and if so, does the binding work when you move it off the tab onto the form itself?

Answer (score 0):

Binding to `ComboBox.SelectedValue` should work, but only in case when you add items through `ComboBox.DataSource`.

```
public class Model
{
    public string StateBar { get; set; }
}

 // In the form

var states = new List<string> { "Alabama", "California" };

combobox.DataSource = states;
combobox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", _model, "StateBar", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Binding to `SelectedItem` should work in all cases.